# Is Apache Tomcat built on Apache Web Server platform?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

Recently our Software Analytic provider ([NETTRACKER](http://netinsight.unica.com/products/NetTracker.htm)) sent us a plugin in order to be able to capture visitors in a better way.  This plugin is for Apache 1.x and Apache 2.x.  They said and I quote

> that since Apache Tomcat is built on Apache HTTP server the configuration of the plugin should be the same.

I have looked for a httpd.conf in our tomcat deployment but we cannot find one, the only configuration that is similar to that one is the server.xml under the /conf directory.

If someone has better information regarding these two incredible products (Apache HTTP server and Apache Tomcat) I will greatly appreciate to draw the differences.

EDIT:
In case you are curious we know that Apache Web Server and Tomcat can work together using the mod_jk option and other proxys.  But this will be too complex for our deployment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apache Tomcat and Apache HTTP are completely different server technologies. It is impossible to use a plugin for Apache HTTP server with Tomcat.

Apache HTTP server is developed in C and so are the plug-ins. On the contrary Tomcat is now completely developed in Java. Tomcat doesn't only serve static content, but it can also serve JSP pages and servlets.

Tomcat is used for hosting Java Web Applications. It can sure serve static content - you can host a web application using only Tomcat. Secure connections are supported and the performance is also very good (comparable with the performance of HTTP server).

A plain installation of Apache serves static content. Using the appropriate plug-ins, HTTP requests can be redirected to an application server (Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish) or a script language interpreter (PHP). With this way dynamic content can be generated. The big advantages of Apache are the numerous plug-ins available, which allows administrators to configure and monitor web sites any way they want and that is the most widespread server available. This makes it the most secure solution, since it is thoroughly tested and any discovered flaw is corrected very quickly.

The best solution would be to use Tomcat proxied by an Apache server. It isn't so difficult to set up. If you can't do this, then you can't take advantage of Apache's plug-ins.

Comment: That's great to know about using HTTP server to route requests to Tomcat - I'm using both right now, and this will be a great little trick!

Comment: The best solution would be to use mod_proxy. There must be a relevant question in SO.

Answer (score 7):

You see this confusion all the time. Many people think that Apache is a web server where in reality it is the name of an organization that has a web server project called "[The Apache HTTP Server Project](http://httpd.apache.org/)". In short the web server is called HTTPD (D as in daemon or Unix process).

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is another Apache project. This project implements a Java servlet engine to serve JSP pages and servlets. Tomcat and HTTPD have nothing to do with each other. However, you can set up HTTPD and Tomcat so that they work together. This way you can have HTTPD serve all static content, do URL rewriting and much more fancy stuff that the built in Tomcat web server can't do (or can't do very well). Whenever a JSP page is requested, HTTPD will pass the request on to Tomcat. Tomcat will process the request and will hand the output back to HTTPD which in turn will send it to the client.

Apache has many [interesting projects](http://www.apache.org). E.g. there is also a project called [Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) which is a Java Enterprise server (J2EE). You can e.g. choose to embed Tomcat inside Geronimo to handle requests for JSP's and servlets where Geronimo does the more enterprisy stuff (LDAP, Messaging etc.). And you guessed it probably already, you can use HTTPD as a static content server for Geronimo as well.

Answer (score 3):

totally bogus.  Apache httpd plugins are written in C, Tomcat is pure Java.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a Java servlet engine.  It can be hosted under Apache or IIS or quite a number of other external facing web servers.  It sounds like you may be currently running your Tomcat instance standalone...

If you serve the JSP/servlets off of port 8080 and have it do things standalone, on the same host machine that Apache is running on, this can allow you to have them loosely coupled.  Having multiple web servers fielding independent requests is not recommended, especially if you want to use server-based authentication along with Apache.  Typically, you have one outside facing server that shepherds everything through it...  Apache does this quite well, and the plugin you mention probably relies on this type of setup (everything gets wired through Apache) for its features/capabilities, based on your brief description of it.

If you would like to serve up your Tomcat servlets under Apache, you could configure apache to forward a class of URIs to your tomcat server instances.  you could achieve this type of forwarding through mod_rewrite.  this is a slower option performance-wise, as it adds slight overhead on everything you server up.  You could also proxy incoming requests via a CGI mechanism similarly, from Apache to Tomcat.

*mod_jk* **will simplify deployment and increase performance** for placing Tomcat into an Apache server config.  It is pretty painless to configure if you follow the docs, so I am not sure what you mean by "too complex" for your deployment -- if you want Apache and have Tomcat already, it would seem only a matter of slight config changes to get *mod_jk* downloaded and installed.

Comment: This answer is only confusing.